# I converted a string into a list when I used another variable to access a list I am getting a type error, how do I access the list now

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

```py
print("<<== program to select and display words of an user input string ==>>")
s=str(input("enter a string:   "))
split1=s.split()
len1=len(split1)
header1="----------------------------------------------"
heading="printing words and ther indexes"
print(header1)
print(heading.center(45))
print(header1)
for x in range(0,len1):
     print("        ",x,"---->",split1[x])
print(header1)
print('')
print('')
g=input('enter the index of the word to display:  ')
print(split1[g])
```

I am getting:

```py
line 16, in <module>
    print(split1[g])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: `g` is `str` because `input` returns a `str` object. You want an int, then `g = int(input(...))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input()` returns `string` by default. You have to use `int()` to convert it to an integer because index can't be a string.
So, it needs to be like this:

```py
g = int(input('enter the index of the word to display:  '))
print(split1[g])
```

Edit: I got it what you're trying to do using variable `g`
For that, you have to use index() like this

```
g = input('enter the index of the word to display:  ')
print(split1.index(g))
```

Comment: I've input a b c  this was the error

Comment: 15, in <module>
    g = int(input('enter the index of the word to display:  '))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'

Comment: It works fine here. Please double check it. First a b c then 1 so output will be b. It means your second input has to be an integer.

Comment: its because you enter `a` and not a number @karthik___12345

Comment: @karthik___12345 Could you clarify what's the expected input for `input('enter the index of the word to display:  ')`. Since the message mentions index, most people would assume the input is int values only

Comment: the input would be 0 1 or 2 and the output would be the list member corresponding to that list index

Comment: I think the answer above should work in that scenario. When the program prompt `enter the index of the word to display: `, did you enter `a` instead of an integer? I think that's probably why you got that error message

Comment: @potato_noodles I have just edited my answer. You were looking for something like that? First input a b c then a so output will be 0 which is the index of a

Comment: @Pythonlearner can we do it the other way too?

Comment: Maybe yes, I'm looking into that. You're welcome